# How to generate create view script postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Please I will know if anyone has a script or knows how to to generate a create view script in PostgreSQL

I have tried to generate the scripts using below SQL but unable:

```
select table_schema as schema_name,
       table_name as view_name,
       view_definition
from information_schema.views
where table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
order by schema_name,
         view_name;
```

Comment: you are trying to get view definitions of existing views. it is correct only. what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Your query works for me.